# I have require is not defined error

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, requirejs

Trying to implement datatables row-details functionality(https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/row-details) in my 
laravel 5.5.40/ Voyager template( "tcg/voyager": "^1.0" )/ Bootstrap 3.3.7 application
I encountered an error:

```
app.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
```

Googling, I found a decision :

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
```

But I got an error:

```
articles:915 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I found which files are attached in the file config/voyager.php:

```
   ...
    // Here you can specify additional assets you would like to be included in the master.blade
    'additional_css' => [
        'css/bootstrap-tagsinput-typeahead.css',
        'css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css',
        'css/bootstrap-treeview.css',
        'css/customisation.css',
        'css/spectrum.css',
    ],

    'additional_js' => [
        'js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js',
        'js/spectrum.js',
    ],
   ...
```

Can you give a hint, which file/plugin have I to attach to the list above?
In the project I found a file `/node_modules/webpack/lib/RequireJsStuffPlugin.js`
Is it what I need and how to attach it and how?

Thanks!

MODIFIED :
after googlingI I installed

```
npm install requirejs
```

with output

```
+ requirejs@2.3.5
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 26.245s
```

But it  did not help, I still get error :

```
ReferenceError: require is not
```

Have to include requirejs in some config files or in my script and how if yes?

MODIFIED 2:

With resource [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)
I try to fix the error by example :

> I just wrote this JavaScript code (using Prototype for DOM
>   manipulation):

For tis I copied file /public/js/require.js ( Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.7.2 )
and file public/js/require.js by url https://gist.github.com/nornagon/284442

and in my blade template :

```
<script src="/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="/js/require.js"></script>
@section('javascript')
```

and got error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
    at observeStandardEvent (prototype.js:6950)
    at observe (prototype.js:6940)
    at HTMLScriptElement._methodized [as observe] (prototype.js:456)
    at require.js:21
    at showArticleListing (articles:1021)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (articles:896)
    at c (app.js:24)
    at u (app.js:24)
```

on a line :

```
    var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
```

On the link above there were several example of attaching js files.
But my case is different , as having error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
```

I tried to include Handlebars, but in my project  there is no any file like Handlebars.js...
?

MODIFIED 3:

In the comments of the example there was fixing issue using Mustache.js:
https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1511
I follow it, as :

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')


    <table class="table table-bordered" id="users-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>Updated At</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

@stop

@push('scripts')

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>

    <script id="details-template" type="mustache/x-tmpl">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Full name:</td>
            <td><%name%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><%email%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Extra info:</td>
            <td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </script>

    <script  >

        $(function() {

            Mustache.tags = ["<%", "%>"];
            var template = $('#details-template').html();

            console.log("template::")
            console.log( template )

            var table= $('#users-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{!! route('get_users') !!}',
                columns: [
                    {
                        "className":      'details-control',
                        "orderable":      false,
                        "searchable":     false,
                        "data":           null,
                        "defaultContent": ''
                    },

                    { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                    { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                    { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
                    { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
                    { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' }
                ]
            });


            // Add event listener for opening and closing details
            $('#users-table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                console.log( '-1' )
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                console.log("-2 tr::")
                console.log( tr )

                var row = table.row( tr );
                console.log("-3 row::")
                console.log( row )


                if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                }
                else {
                    // Open this row
//                    row.child( template(row.data()) ).show();
                    row.child( Mustache.render(template, row.data()) ).show();
                    console.log("row::")
                    console.log( row )


                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

@endpush
```

And I got error :

```
jquery.dataTables.min.js:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at Ga (jquery.dataTables.min.js:59)
    at ga (jquery.dataTables.min.js:45)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:383)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:136)
    at jQuery.fn.init.m [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:83)
    at jQuery.fn.init.P.h.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:159)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index:89)
    at fire (jquery.js:3119)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3231)
```

Looking at the console the template code was found:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K01I.jpg
as there were misunderstanding of  where to put the template

```
I have no error if to remove the definition of the first column:
                    {
                        "className":      'details-control',
                    ...
```

Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: include Require.js file in your script and here is a link to how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: You can not use require() function on your browser side javascript. It's a function only available to NodeJS. If you are still trying to write modular js code. You would have to bundle your client side code with bundlers like browserify or webpack that interpret the require() function and bundle the js modules in one file.

Comment: Yes, i have webpack.mix.js file in my project with default lines app.js and 
 app.scss. But how to bundle to have acees to require( in my project? Please, link how to make it.